# PHP 7.1 Currency Calculations

Tags: php, laravel

I have updated to PHP 7.1 and this simple calculation now returns as 'A non well formed numeric value encountered' error

```
    $balance = "-16,438.56";
    $amount = "1000.00";

    return $balance-$amount;
```

I need help knowing how to manage this
Thanks

Comment: those are both strings!

Comment: This is an example it is being pulled from inputs and would work in previous PHP versions

Comment: I'd say `"-16,438.56"` is not well formed, because of the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the comma from $balance.

`$balance = "-16438.56";`

Comment: Thank you this appears to work, other suggestions such as (float) return an incorrect calculation. This appears to of changed in PHP V 7.1 and above

Comment: The output has never be correct with the exact input given by you. Please refer to this [sandbox example](https://3v4l.org/SMB3R) and have a look at all included PHP versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to float values.

```
$balance = -16438.56;
$amount = 1000.00;

echo $balance-$amount;

$ -17438.56
```

Answer (score 1):

Your balance has comma in it so first remove the comma. You can also type hint if you want to be sure.

```
$balance = str_replace(',','',$balance);
return (float) $balance - (float) $amount;
```

Comment: This breaks in a locale that uses a comma for decimals.

Comment: @BartFriederichs then you have to remove the commas for the calculations, because PHP's float type isn't compatible with those commas, then re-add the commas after calculation, duh. and we have a function to do this exact thing, called number_format()

Answer (score 1):

php's `-` operator can cast strings to floats for you implicitly, but that cast is not compatible with the thousand-step-commas, so get rid of the commas, do your calculations, and re-add the commas after calculation, eg

```
$balance = "-16,438.56";
$amount = "1000.00";
return number_format ( (( float ) (str_replace ( ",", "", $balance ))) - (( float ) (str_replace ( ",", "", $amount ))), 2, ".", "," );
```